# WAS stops after iisreset after enabling startMode and preloadEnabled on appPools

Tags: iis, windows-10, was, iisreset

Following the steps in this article I am trying to turn on preloadEnabled and startMode in my applications (I have about 20 WCF services in their own app pools and then 3 client sites) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization

Now when I do an iisreset, WAS dies immediately. If I go back and start it manually and then the W3PS, everything starts like I want it to.

Is there any hope for being able to do an iisreset ever again?

Doing it with /stop and /start works fine. It's literally just the bang turnaround of no flags that's an issue.

Event code for WAS fail was 5011 and the code was 8007006d

IIS v 10.0.15063.0

Windows 10 1703 (15063.726)

Comment: what's event viewer say when you do `IISReset` vs. `IISReset /stop` then `IISRESET /start`?

Comment: @S.Walker added a tiny bit more detail on the error code

Comment: you are only getting a single error, not multiple?

Comment: I just flushed the event logs, and am retesting. I talked to some team members and we think it's a dependency in our app trying to keep a thing open and failing to restart.

Answer (score 0):

For the [future internet visitor to this question](https://m.xkcd.com/979/), what we discovered in our testing and working through the bug was that we have a background thread related to our pubsub internally that isn't shutting down cleanly, and is causing the process to hang before the reload has a chance to happen, causing corruption in WAS.

Starting the dependency stopped the issue for us during the next round of testing, and now we get to go research a new bug internally. Fun times.